# Cannot fetch from localhost with Authorization header

Tags: reactjs, express

I'm having a hard time sending a get request to my expressjs backend with the `fetch` method.

```
fetch('http://localhost:9000', { method: 'GET', headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken.accessToken}` }}).then(() => {
    debugger
}).catch((error) => {
    debugger
})
```

Based on what I could read, this seems correct - The request is however not reaching the API.

I tried constructing the options object like so, without any luck:

```
const options = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: headers
};
```

Without the headers, my request reaches the API. Anyway, the error that I'm getting is this:

> error: TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: I would expect the header `Authorization: Bearer xxx`, not `Authentication: Bearer xxx`.

Comment: I just tried that - It is still the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Log out the value of `accessToken.accessToken` is it valid / as expected?  Does your express server have a middleware to check for auth token?  Does this work as expected?

Comment: Yes, everything is working from Postman.

Comment: @DeBraid yes it has middleware to check for the token. But the request doesn't reach my express application - This does however happen when I leave out the headers.

Comment: what is the output of `curl http://localhost:9000`?  What is the full error from the browser console?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I found a solution, basically I added this middleware in my Express application to allow CORS,

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {

    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");

    next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make that request from an origin other than `http://localhost:9000`, the `Authorization` header will cause the browser to make a CORS preflight request `OPTIONS http://localhost:9000` before the GET request, and if that fails, the GET request would not be made.

You must ensure that your server handles the preflight, e.g., through the [`cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) middleware.